# Add Function Base

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

The HTML is this:

```
<img src="img/team/max.jpg" alt="max" class="kat"/>
<ul class="referenzen">
    <li>

        <a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-1" href="img/logo.jpg">
            <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-2" href="img/logo.jpg">
            <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt=""/>
            </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

If i click the img class="kat" the fancybox should start with the a tag elements. And not with the class="kat" Element.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: click what? There's no event handler?

Comment: Need more code, preferably a jsfiddle.

Comment: i want to click the first image that has the class="kat". If i click this. I would like to start the fancybox, but with the a tags they are included i the li. I know i need a event handler but i don't know how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you're asking for, but how about something like this: Register an event handler for the first image and simulate a click on the first fancyboxed-image:

```
$('img.kat').click(function() {
    $(this).next().find('.fancybox:first').click();
});
```

Comment: or just simply `$('img.kat').click(function(){$(".fancybox").click()});`